# Ionic angularJS, get data and bind to view

Tags: ajax, angularjs, wcf, ionic-framework

I am creating a service to download data from WCF service and then I am binding it to the ionic view. I am not able to bind the data to the view, I keep getting error "profileData is undefined", I have tried to follow the ionic online tutorial.

**Inside of config**

```
.state('app.settings', {
                url: '/settings',
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/settings.html',
                        controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    profileData: function(ProfileService){
                        return ProfileService.getUserProfile()
                    }
                }
            })
```

**Profile service**

```
.service('ProfileService', function ($q, $http, $localstorage, loginSharedData, Base64) {
        return {
            getUserProfile: function () {
                console.log('inside service');
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var promise = deferred.promise;

                var _postData = {
                    "apiKey": Base64.decode($localstorage.get('secureToken')),
                    "userId": Base64.decode(loginSharedData.userid)
                };
                setTimeout(function(){
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/snc/Service.Svc/GetUserProfile',
                    data: _postData,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: "json"
                }).then(function (response) {
                    console.log('inside service success');
                    var _data = response.data;
                    if (_data.GetUserProfileResult.status) {
                        console.log('Profile downloaded');
                        deferred.resolve(_data.GetUserProfileResult);
                    }
                    else
                        deferred.reject('Failed to get profile.');
                }, function (response) {
                    console.log('inside profile service fail');
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response.status == 0) {
                        deferred.reject('Failed to get profile');
                    }
                })}, 1000);

                promise.success = function (fn) {
                    promise.then(fn);
                    return promise;
                }
                promise.error = function (fn) {
                    promise.then(null, fn);
                    return promise;
                }
                return promise;
            }
        }
    })
```

**The Controller**

```
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function ($scope, ProfileService, Base64) {
        $scope.profileData = profileData;
}
```

The profileData is undefined in the controller, can you point to the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inject profileData to the controller as well:

```
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function ($scope, ProfileService, Base64, profileData) {
        $scope.profileData = profileData;
}
```

btw - you probably don't need to inject ProfileService

Comment: I tried it, but for some reason, I can't go to settings. It changes the URL but nothing comes up on the screen. The button that cause the navigation is in menu.html, bound to AppCtrl and calls "goToSettings()" which does following "$state.go('app.settings')" , it was working earlier.

Comment: thanks mate, its working now. Can you point me to some tutorial about sharing data across controllers?

Comment: You ninja me before I could finish writing my comment. hehe

Comment: @Oro Drori, I can see the data in the console, but I am getting following error when I try to bind "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: profileDataProvider <- profileData <- ProfileCtrl"

Comment: First - read this article about promises (#4 in particular) - http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Comment: profileData: function(ProfileService){ <-- you replaced ProfileService with profileData

Comment: If you are asking, then no, I added it to the controller as you said in the answer.

Comment: About sharing data between controllers: Create a directive, and share data via attributes or use a service to hold the data, and notify about updates using $broadcast to $rootScope

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88408/discussion-between-ori-drori-and-hitin).